# OpenLayers 3 Disable Multi-Select

Tags: openlayers-3

Is there a way to have a `selectInteraction` in OpenLayers 3 that only allows one feature to be selected at a time?

Answer (score 14):

**define select interaction as follow**:

```
select = new ol.interaction.Select (
    toggleCondition: ol.events.condition.never
)
```

Comment: Fix the answer, it should be `select = new ol.interaction.Select ({
    toggleCondition: ol.events.condition.never
})`

Comment: If anyone is using VueLayers, I got this to work by putting `import { never } from 'ol/events/condition'` at the top of the scrpt and then defining it in the `data` block as `never` and then specifying `:toggle-condition="never"` in the `<vl-interaction-select>` component.

Answer (score 2):

Not really sure I understood well.

If you go to [the API doc for OpenLayers 3.4](http://openlayers.org/en/v3.4.0/apidoc/ol.interaction.Select.html?unstable=true) and untick `Stable Only` on the page top right, you will see a `multi` option to manage this.
Normally, according to the doc, what you are asking is already by default.

> **Multi** A boolean that determines if the default behaviour should select only single features or all (overlapping) features at the clicked map position. Default is false i.e single select

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. The `multi` option is for selecting multiple features with one click. I want to turn off the ability to hold the `shift` key and select multiple features.

Answer (score 1):

For OpenLayers4 this can easily be done by combining conditions.

For example a condition that only selects on singleClick and not when shiftKey is pressed:

```
const select = new Select({
  condition: (mapBrowserEvent) => {
    return singleClick(mapBrowserEvent) && !shiftKeyOnly(mapBrowserEvent)},
  layers: [layer]
});
```

Find more conditions in the API doc: http://openlayers.org/en/latest/apidoc/module-ol_events_condition.html